# How do I attach an .mdf to sql2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Running sp_attach_single_file_db gives this error:

```
The log scan number (10913:125:2) passed to log scan in database 'myDB' is not valid
```

Isn't it supposed to re-create the log file?

How else would I be able to attach/repair that .mdf file?

Comment: there is no log file ;-) and it's just dummy data, just need it to work again so i can continue to dev... basically it used to work like 2 months ago, then i had to re-install sql2005 (express) and now i cannot re-attach it... not sure if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked, when I installed another one (with .ldf log file) then the one in question, then detached the first one again. Don't ask me why.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what mode your database was in when it was detached, it's possible there are uncommitted/unwritten transactions in that log file that are needed to attach the database, otherwise there would be data loss.  Do you know what recovery mode you were in when it was detached?